# wamp server does not start: Windows 7, 64Bit

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-7, 64-bit

I am trying to install wamp server (following is the exact setup name) on windows 7, 64Bit OS. But it never starts, icon stays in orange color meaning some services did not start.

```
wampserver2.2e-php5.3.13-httpd2.2.22-mysql5.5.24-x64
```

I have been searching from last 3hours but did not find any solution.

```
 Port 80 is not in use.
```

In windows services, when I try to start wampapache service manually, it throws following error:

```
Windows could not start the wampapache service on Local Computer. Error 1053: The service did not respond ot the start or control request in a timely fashion.

apache_error.log is empty.
```

Things use to work fine in windows XP.

May be this is a repeated thread, but I did go through similar posts. But nothing worked!

Please help!!

Comment: Any interesting error in Event Viewer?

Comment: I dont see any apache logs. There are MySQL events but no apache events. :(

Answer (score 1):

I just resolved this problem on a Windows 2008 Server.  The solution was to install the C++ 2010 runtime library.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Apache was trying to listen in 192.168.1.6:80 where I was getting an Internet Information Service Page. I changed httpd.conf to listen to 127.0.0.1:80 and it did the trick.